# Unsafe version of writeTVar

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm using a list of `TVar`s that are accessed by multiple threads. 
However, there is one performance-critical section in my code that reads as follows:

```
 sequence [ atomically $ writeTVar tvar1 someValue | tvar1 <- listOfTVars ]
```

It is guaranteed that, at the time when this code is reached, no other thread will be accessing *any* of the `TVar`s in `listOfTVars` until `sequence` has completed, neither by reading nor writing.

Does GHC expose any primitives that would allow me to "unsafely" perform these value updates? **My goal** would be to do this faster without going through the STM-overhead of committing a transaction for each of them. In other words, I don't need the atomicity that STM provides for `writeTVar`; Instead, I would just need a fast way to update the values stored in the `TVar`s.

Answer (score 2):

Looking around I do not see any exposed primitives.

The documentation says you can use `unsafePerformIO` with `atomically`, but warns that it may subvert some of the guarantees that it offers: [Control.Monad.STM.atomically](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.5.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-STM.html#v:atomically). Apparently `unsafeDupablePerformIO` has better performance than `unsafePerformIO`, but more caveats. If it is performance critical it is worth benchmarking to see if these offer any performance advantages.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import Control.Monad.STM
import Control.Monad
import System.IO.Unsafe

t1 <- newTVarIO "Hello"
t2 <- newTVarIO "Goodbye"
unsafeDupablePerformIO $ sequence $ (\t -> atomically $ writeTVar t "Hola") <$>  [t1,t2] 
unsafeDupablePerformIO $ sequence $ (putStrLn <=< readTVarIO) <$> [t1,t2]
```

Comment: Just a basic question: Why is `unsafeDupablePerformIO (atomically $ writeTVar t "bla")` faster than just running `atomically $ writeTVar t "bla"`?

Comment: It has less compiler guarantees than monad IO or even unsafePerformIO and can be dangerous in a multi threaded environment especially if you are writing, reading would be a little less dangerous. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the GHC internals to give a more in depth answer but there are a few details here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html

Comment: I would be curious to hear more about the actual problem. Maybe there is another way to design it so you do not have the end bottleneck of writing every thing sequentially. For example if instead of sequentially updating a list of tvars you instead had a vector of tvars, slice it (O(1) operation) into a few smaller pieces, fork for each sub vector and update them separately it would probably run faster.